# Minimum System Requirements to run Recommendation in Predictionio

Tags: python, apache-spark, recommendation-engine, data-science, predictionio

I tried to have predictionio integrate with my app. I used recommendation Engine deployment as in [quick start](http://docs.prediction.io/templates/recommendation/quickstart/) in Predictionio website. 
Faced lot of issues but able to build the engine. 
I tried to train the model using `pio train`. But it gave an error saying "`java.lang.StackOverflowError`". So it means memory is not enough in my server. Then I tried to increase the memory by using `pio train -- --driver-memory 5g --executor-memory 5g`. Still I am getting the same error
(I am using 4 cores, 6GB RAM Ubuntu 14.04 server).

SO I want to know what is the minimum server requirements have Predictionio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimum Requirements can be found in [here](http://actionml.com/docs/pio_quickstart)